# why is my scheduler function not working with flask in python?

Tags: python, flask, scheduler

I'm making an alarm clock on a web server with flask on Python. I want to be able to cancel alarms as well as set different ones. However when trying to use the sched function, I encounter this error when I set the alarm:

```
(print_job() missing 1 required positional argument)
```

```py
@app.route('/scheduler')
def print_job(name):
    print(name)
    s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
    e1 = s.enter(3, 1, print_job, ("Notification #1 ",))
    e2 = s.enter(1, 2, print_job, ("Notification #2",))

    s.run(blocking=False)
    alarm_time = request.args.get("alarm")
    if alarm_time:
        # convert alarm_time to a delay
        delay = time_conversions.hhmm_to_seconds(alarm_time) - time_conversions.hhmm_to_seconds(time_conversions.current_time_hhmm())
        print(delay)
        #s.enter(int(delay), 1, print, ["Testy test",])
        return'<head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30;url=\'/\'"></head> \
                <form action="/" method="get"> \
                <input type="datetime-local" name="alarm"> \
                <input type="submit"> \
                </form>'
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your `print_job` function requires an argument (`name`), and it's not receiving one.

[According to the flask documentation for urls with variables](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#variable-rules), you need to add a variable declaration to your `@app.route()` decorator:

```py
@app.route('/scheduler/<name>')
def print_job(name):
    # ...
```

But, since your function doesn't seem to be using the `name` variable, you could just remove it instead:

```py
@app.route('/scheduler')
def print_job():
    # ...
```

Comment: hmm thanks for the answer but it still doesnt seem to work.

Comment: @the_napster after changing your code to test my answer, did you get a new error message? If so, please post the modified code as well as the error message in an edit to **your original question** (not as a reply to this comment).

Answer (score 0):

`print_job() missing 1 required positional argument`

This is a reference to your route not having an argument in it, while your function definition demands one. All you need to do to get past this error is add an argument to your flask route.

```
@api.route('/scheduler/<name>')
def print_job(name):
    print(name)
```

Alternatively, you could just remove the argument from your function definition and you'll be good to go. Happy coding!